# How to properly use JTI claims with JWT to prevent replay attacks?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-security, jwt

I have created some REST APIs using Spring and implemented Spring Security with JWT for authentication. My front end runs AngularJs and consumes these rest APIs receiving JSON responses. The JWT authentication works fine but it allows for simple copying and pasting of request parameters and headers from the browser's console into Postman or any other REST client to fetch successful responses even from protected APIs from the back end.

I am trying to solve this problem by using JTI claims within the JWT. I plan to use distinct JTI value for each request post authentication so that simply stealing headers from browser wouldn't work.

Now after going through plenty of resources available online, it is still not clear to me whether the client or the server is supposed to set the JTI value in the JWT.

As per my understanding, if i do this on the server side, i will have to send a new JWT with every response and expect it in the next request from the client while maintaining a record of used JTIs in a database. But if an attacker figures this out they'll just have to use a token from a previous request and they can comfortably interact with my APIs thereafter.

On the other hand if i do this on the client side, i'll have to keep the secret signing key of the JWT and the logic for JTI generation in the javascript code so that it may append a JTI value and hash the token again. 
My questions then are:

1. What is the correct way of implementing this? Am i missing something or going in the wrong direction altogether?
2. Is there any other solution i may implement to disallow or unauthenticate any requests coming from a non browser client(The way it happens in legacy Spring MVC applications using Jsps)?

Any help is highly appreciated. Been stuck on this for a long time now.

Comment: I guess you want to secure your client against csrf so i'd suggest this link for further reading: https://stormpath.com/blog/csrf-protection-jwt-spring-security

Answer (score 10):

I can't speak to Java/Spring, but I can try to clarify your concerns regarding JWTs and JTI claims.

Implementing a JTI to uniquely identify a JWT can help prevent [replay attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack) where an attacker sends the same JWT to make a request.  The server would generate the JTI value and send it along with a new JWT on every response.  When receiving a new request, the server would have to validate the JTI value (to ensure that it had not been used before).  Implementing this does require some sort of persistent storage on the server, which can look more or less like traditional sessions, so it feels a bit weird since one of the advertised benefits of JWT is a "stateless application".

You're absolutely correct about your concern of a man-in-the-middle attack: if someone DOES intercept the JWT (and its single-use JTI) and then makes a request BEFORE you do, their request will be considered valid and YOUR subsequent requests will appear to the server to be "replays" (and the server would consider them invalid).

Comment: Does this mean the only benefit to using JTI is less storage? Saving the JTI strings and checking if they've been issued versus checking the whole token.

Comment: No, the benefit of implementing a unique identifier (the JTI) on your JWTs is a security benefit -- implementing a system that properly creates, stores, and checks JTIs takes more resources/storage because a proper implementation will create a new ID for each request made with each JWT.  Instead of just determining whether or not the JWT is valid, the system can tell whether or not the JWT has ever been used before.

Comment: I think what C.M. is saying is that you could just store the JWT itself in a DB (or something) to record whether it was ever seen before, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @DylanYoung The access token signature is intended for authenticating the message's origin, while access token claims are intended to make authorization decisions. Typically, your authz layer will be concerned with the relationship between your claims and the resources you're trying to access, not with whether forged tokens have made it deep into the system. A JTI ensures the authz layer is able to work with whatever you're using for revocation. If your JWTs are small, you could store them as an optimization, like how some DNS servers use entire packets as cache keys to skip a decoding step.